# Having problems using Android SDK on Netbeans on a mac

Tags: android, macos, netbeans, sdk

I've installed the Android SDK using this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDjkHJVC0R0 and i used a different tutorial (I cannot find it again, it was deep within google) to link the paths on Netbeans.

I set up the url for automatic updating, installed every version, and even installed the google files. But when i click "New Project", i get this the normal new project page, but the 'Target Platform' window is completely empty. It greys out the 'Next' and 'Finish' buttons, and in red words it says 'Target Android Platform must be specified!'

I remember somewhere that i had to make a path to my downloaded SDK, i think i made the right path, but i don't think i did.

What can i do? I can't even start making a new blank application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add platforms following the [Step 4 from "Installing the SDK"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#AddingComponents) documentation.

Comment: I did do that, but the platforms still don't show up in the window.

Comment: Do you have indicated to Netbeans where is the SDK? Consider using eclipse ;-)

Comment: I have netbeans pointed to the folder that appeared when i unzipped the SDK. It is the same folder that was the target of the downloading when i installed all of the files. Yet the window is still empty.